# Matrix exponentials, computing the product of $\exp(-iBt)$ and $\exp(-iB^{-1}t)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quantum-mechanics, matrix-exponential

Suppose I have some matrix exponential $U(t)=\exp(-iAt)$ where $t$ is some real valued number, $A$ is a hermitian matrix (so $U(t)$ is unitary) where $A=B+B^{-1}$ and $B$ is unitary. Because $B$ and $B^{-1}$ commute we have 
$$ U(t)=\exp(-iBt).\exp(-iB^{-1}t)$$ Can this expression for $U(t)$ then be simplified any further without diagonalising $B$ and $B^{-1}$?

Comment: Even in 1-d, I see no good way of simplifying $e^{-ibt}e^{-it/b}$...

Comment: Since $B$ is unitary, $B^{-1} = B^\dagger$. This means that $\exp(-iB^{-1}t) = \exp(iBt)^\dagger$. Writing $U(t) = \exp(-i B t)\exp(iBt)^\dagger$ at least makes it clear that $U$ is unitary.

Comment: @eyeballfrog true. So lets say I diagonalised $B=V\Lambda V^\dagger$ then I should get
\begin{align}
U(t)&=V \exp(-i \Lambda t) V^\dagger (V \exp(i \Lambda t) V ^\dagger)^\dagger\\
&=V \exp(-i \Lambda t) V^\dagger V \exp(-i \Lambda^\dagger t) V^\dagger\\
&= V \exp(-i (\Lambda + \Lambda^\dagger)t)V^\dagger

\end{align}
Since $B$ is unitary its eigenvalues have modulus 1 and hence $\Lambda$ is unitary as well.

Comment: @amitsett Yes. And since $\Lambda$ is diagonal, $\Lambda + \Lambda^\dagger = 2\mathrm{Re}[\Lambda]$. Not sure how much this helps, but it's neat.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious simplification is
\begin{align}
U(t)
&=\exp(-itB)\exp(-itB^{-1})\\
&=\exp(-it(B+B^{-1}))\ \text{ (because $B$ commutes with $B^{-1}$)}\\
&=\exp(-it(B+B^\ast))
\end{align}
but you probably already know this.

Comment: Yep. I guess to be more clear I'm trying to break it up into exponentials of matrices that are easier to exponentiate. I could diagonalise $B$ such that $B=V\Lambda V^\dagger$ then 

$$\exp(-itB)=V\exp(-it \Lambda)V^\dagger$$ 

However I want to check if there's any further tricks I could use before finding eigenvectors and eigenvalues.